# findFirst method in SinglyLinkedList

Tags: java, methods, find, linked-list

I just updated my code, if someone can help me...in my findFirst method I wanted to look for the first node that includes the element and if such a node is found it returns the node otherwise null...so far in my method I did finding a node but Im not sure how to find the first node...how I would be able to do that ? this is what I have so far..thanks...

```
public SLNode<E> findFirst(E element){
    SLNode<E> cursor = head.getSuccessor();
    while(cursor != null){
        if(cursor.getElement() !=null && cursor.getElement().equals(element))
            return cursor;
        cursor = cursor.getSuccessor();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Below are my actual classes

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<E> {
private final SLNode<E> head;
private final SLNode<E> tail;
int length;

// creates an empty list
public SinglyLinkedList() {
    head = new SLNode<E>();
    tail = new SLNode<E>();
    head.setSuccessor(tail);
    length = 0;
}


// adds new node on beginning of the list
public void add(E element) {
    SLNode<E> node = new SLNode<E>(element, null);
    node.setSuccessor(head.getSuccessor());
    head.setSuccessor(node);
}

//removes a first node on beginning of the list
public boolean remove(E element) {
    SLNode<E> previous = head;
    SLNode<E> current = head.getSuccessor();
    while (current != tail) {
        if (current.getElement().equals(element)) {
            previous.setSuccessor(current.getSuccessor());
            //successor is next
            return true;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current.getSuccessor();
    }
    return false;
}

public SLNode<E> findFirst(E element){
    /*Shown At the Top as part of the Question*/
}


// adds new node on beginning of the list
public void add(SLNode<E> node) {
    node.setSuccessor(head.getSuccessor());
    head.setSuccessor(node);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    SLNode<E> cursor = head.getSuccessor();
    while (cursor != tail) {
    sb.append(cursor.getElement()).append(" ");
    cursor = cursor.getSuccessor();
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    return sb.toString();
}


}
```

SLnode class

```
public class SLNode<E> {
    private E element;
    private SLNode<E> successor;

    public SLNode() {
        element = null;
        successor = null;
    }

    public SLNode(E theElement, SLNode<E> theSuccessor) {
        element = theElement;
        successor = theSuccessor;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(E newElement) {
        element = newElement;
    }

    public SLNode<E> getSuccessor() {
        return successor;
    }

    public void setSuccessor(SLNode<E> newSuccessor) {
        successor = newSuccessor;
    }

    public Object getPrevious() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void setPrevious(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public void setNext(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public Object getNext111() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public Object getNext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public Object getPrevious1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void setPrevious1(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    public Object getNext1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void setNext11(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void setNext1(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    public Object getNext11() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't read in detail all of your code, but it seems that you skipped the first element (by calling successor right off the bat) and the last element (!= tail).

Comment: I just updated my code ..will you please tell me if I did right ?

Comment: Why are you re-inventing `LinkedList`? Or if this is homework, please add the `homework` tag